# Show edit tag wiki action in reputation tab like summary tab

Tags: feature-request, reputation, profile-page, tag-wiki

In the summary tab, there is differentiation between tag wiki edits.

[image: Summary tab wiki]

In the reputation tab, there should also be differentiation between tag wiki edits the same as the summary tab. Why don't we have this differentiation in the reputation tab also?

[image: reputation tab wiki]

Comment: I swear I posted something about this, and a developer even commented on it, but I can't find it *anywhere*. o.o I even still have the two images I used on the post.

Comment: @animuson mooo hahahaha **meta conspiracy**?

Comment: I think developers deleted that question :P They are not serious about it. :( @animuson